# Display (render) huge xml file

Tags: xml

I've found a bunch of programs that can **edit** huge XML files, but not render them. I've tried Firefox and Opera, both crash. Any ideas? The filesize is about 75 MB. By render I mean how it looks like in a browser, not the source code. Just like HTML code "transforms" into a web page.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by rendering? Does it have to include xml schema and transformation so you get an actual designed dataset out of your file?
Edit: Also, what kind of filesize are we talking about? Edit2: And please update your question with answers to this comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the xml to be displayed, just wrap the xml in [xmp](http://download.cnet.com/DJ-Java-Decompiler/3000-2213_4-10046809.html) tags and put it in the body of the html page.

If you want to edit, [xmlspy](http://www.altova.com/download.html) or [oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) can help you. Both have free trials.

Comment: I tried to just open the xml file (becuase firefox should display the file correctly) but it crashes. I won't help if I open it as a html file